# How do Django REST api serializers know what model they are associated with?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

I'm extremely new to Django. I've been researching Django as wells as the Django REST api for use with a project I'm doing and I've been browsing the documentation. I came across serialization here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ and I'm just a little confused how the serializer knows which model it is associated with. It seems to me that the only way it could figure out what model it is associated with is from the naming convention.

In the example, they make a class called Comment and then the merely make another serializer class called CommentSerializer. Could someone explain why or how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the django rest framework [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), this is how you can define your serializer

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

As you can see, the model is mentioned in the Meta tags. This is called the ModelSerializer

Comment: Oh ok this makes sense. I guess I should have looked at the documentation a little more thoroughly.